# select node value from json column type

Tags: sql, sqlite, where-clause, jsonpath, sqlite-json1

A table I called `raw_data` with three columns: `ID, timestamp, payload`, the column `paylod` is a `json` type having values such as:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "author_id": "1461871206425108480",
    "created_at": "2022-08-17T23:19:14.000Z",
    "geo": {
      "coordinates": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -0.1094,
          51.5141
        ]
      },
      "place_id": "3eb2c704fe8a50cb"
    },
    "id": "1560043605762392066",
    "text": " ALWAYS @ London, United Kingdom"
  },
  "matching_rules": [
    {
      "id": "1560042248007458817",
      "tag": "london-paris"
    }
  ]
}
```

From this I want to select rows where the `coordinates` is available, such as `[-0.1094,51.5141]`in this case.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM raw_data, json_each(payload) 
WHERE json_extract(json_each.value, '$.data.geo.') IS NOT NULL 
LIMIT 20;
```

Nothing was returned.

**EDIT**

NOT ALL `json` objects have the `coordinates` node. For example this value:

```sql
{
  "data": {
    "author_id": "1556031969062010881",
    "created_at": "2022-08-18T01:42:21.000Z",
    "geo": {
      "place_id": "006c6743642cb09c"
    },
    "id": "1560079621017796609",
    "text": "Dear Desperate sister  say husband no dey oo."
  },
  "matching_rules": [
    {
      "id": "1560077018183630848",
      "tag": "kaduna-kano-katsina-dutse-zaria"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct path is `'$.data.geo.coordinates.coordinates'` and there is no need for `json_each()`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM raw_data
WHERE json_extract(payload, '$.data.geo.coordinates.coordinates') IS NOT NULL;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=397222c0496fb354596ad9ff9252dbce).

Comment: OK, but not all values in that column has the `coordinates` node as in question edit. I check this adding it to the fiddle you show, it results in error.

Comment: @arilwan there is no error: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=05631014161c9edd9427697f04532b93 A row without coordinates is not returned because in that case json_extract() returns null